# Make a group owner of an admin disk

Tags: linux, sftp, file-permissions

Im having a little problem with folders.I have 1 admin and **4 users**. All 4 users are in **one group**.
The problem is that admin have access to 2TB disk (  /media/admin/disk ). I would like that entire group can access to admin folders. Because on that disk I have 4 maps, 1 for each user. (/media/admin/disk/4maps)

So far I was able to give permissions only to a single user at a time. (chown -R user:group /media/admin )

Im using ubuntu server and sftp connection for 4 users.

So how to give permissions to all the users in group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that mentioned 4 users are in group `testgroup`.

```
setfacl -m g:testgroup:rwx /media/admin/disk
```

The above command will grant `testgroup` full access to the directory `/media/admin/disk`

Comment: Thank you for your help, one more question:
I have 4 maps inside that disk  (media/admin/disk/user1 | user2 | etc. ). I would like that user1 can read-write (full premission)  only map user1 and access denid to other maps.(user2,user3)

Comment: @nmatja, is there direct naming correspondence between usernames and map names? Does each map `media/admin/disk/user1, media/admin/disk/user2 etc` contains the existing username `user1`, `user2 ...` ?

Comment: yes it does, the name of user is same as map name - BUT there is no need for that, if that bring problems !